# meaning of “it is just on the shake of hands” and meaning of “got to”

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, word-in-context

> On his coaching mantra, Roche said he never had a contract with any player.
>
> **"It's just on the shake of hands.** I feel that you **got to** have mutual respect. The important thing in tennis is to be an unbelievable athlete. You **got to** move well," he concluded.
>
> <sub>Source: [Zee News, *Roger Federer can play for another 4-5 years: former coach Tony Roche*](http://zeenews.india.com/sports/tennis/roger-federer-can-play-for-another-4-5-years-former-coach-tony-roche_1508378.html)</sub>

1. What does **“it is just on the shake of hands”** mean?
2. What does **“got to”** in this context mean?

Answer (score 3):

“It’s just on the shake of hands” sounds a bit strange to me, but the context indicates that he is making non-technical reference to a **[handshake deal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshake_deal)** in contrast to a (written) contract.

> A handshake deal is a verbal commitment to a transaction. 
> <sub>Source: [Handshake deal
> From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshake_deal)</sub>

---

“Got to” means *must.* Roche is opting for a common colloquial phrasing that omits “have” but can be understood as saying “you’ve got to” (“you have got to”) as below:

> **“Have got to” and “have to”: forms**
>
> **Affirmative form**
>
> “Have (got) to” comes before the main verb:
>
> *You **have to** try these cakes. They are so good.*
>
> It is often contracted, especially in speaking.
>
> *You**’ve got to** press very hard on the doorbell.*
>
> <sub>Source: [*“Have got to” and “have to”*
> from English Grammar Today, via Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/have-got-to-and-have-to)</sub>